# PL/SQL converts name-value pairs to single row table

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Using PL/SQL, how do I convert a table of name-value pairs like this...

```
Name      Value
--------- -------
Firstname   Bob
Surname     Smith
Address1    101 High Street
City        London
Country     UK
```

...to a single row table like this:

```
Firstname Surname Address1        City   Country
--------- ------- --------------- ------ -------
Bob       Smith   101 High Street London UK
```

actually what I need is to convert the name-value pairs to a **SYS_REFCURSOR** as the single row table above

The full story is:
I receive the data as a single string like this (Firstname;Bob;Surname;SmithAddress1;101 High Street;City;London;Country;UK) all I need is to convert this to a SYS_REFCURSOR

I started by creating types

```
TYPE order_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(255);
neworder order_type;
```

so far I managed to do so with name-value pairs

is it a good approach?

Comment: You need to pivot; how depends on which version of Oracle you are using. But why do you want to use PL/SQL for this?

Comment: I just updated my question @Alex  hope it makes things clearer

Comment: What is your oracle version?

Comment: it's Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table t1 (name varchar2(20), value varchar2(20));
insert into t1 values('Firstname','Bob');
insert into t1 values('Surname','Smith');
insert into t1 values('Address1','101 High Street');
insert into t1 values('City','London');
insert into t1 values('Country','UK');

select * from t1 pivot (max(value) for (name) in ('Firstname' as firstname, 'Surname' as surname, 'Address1' as address, 'City' as city, 'Country' as country));
```

Such SQL converts column data into one row.

If you get your data as a separated string with fixed order I would just parse it using combination of `instr('Firstname;Bob;Surname;Smith;Address1;101 High Street;City;London;Country;UK',';',1)` and `substring` function.

Something like:

```
declare
text varchar2(200) := 'Firstname;Bob;Surname;Smith;Address1;101 High Street;City;London;Country;UK';
firstname varchar2(40);
surname varchar2(40);
address varchar2(40);
city varchar2(40);
country varchar2(40);
begin
firstname := substr(text,instr(text,';',1) + 1,instr(text,';',2) - instr(text,';',1));
surname := substr(text,instr(text,';',3) + 1, instr(text,';',4) - instr(text,';',3));
....
end;
```

Comment: the value of the string that I receive is variable, so I can not define only  firstname, surname,..., etc

Comment: @Data-Base ok. If you know the set of parameters you can try to recognize it and parse. If parameters are dynamiacally set you need to go for parsing pairs and then some dynamical pivot

Comment: @Data-Base good to know. Not sure if I helped you at all but it's good that you manage your problem.

Answer (score 0):

came across an interesting utility I didn't know about. dbms_utility.comma_to_table. http://mohsoracle.blogspot.com/2010/04/oracle-breaking-comma-separated-string.html

so if you wanted to use it to return a sys ref cursor from a delimited string maybe something like.

```
/* Formatted on 10/28/2016 9:42:52 AM (QP5 v5.256.13226.35510) */
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc (v_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
   lv_Str_List   VARCHAR2 (1000)
      := 'Firstname, Bob, Surname, Smith, Address, 101 High Street, City, London, Country, UK';
   lb_cnt        BINARY_INTEGER;
   la_Tab_Str    DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY;
BEGIN
   lv_Str_List := '"' || REPLACE (lv_Str_List, ',', '","') || '"';
   -- parse the string into comma separated table
   DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE (lv_Str_List, lb_cnt, la_Tab_Str);

   FOR i IN 1 .. la_Tab_Str.COUNT
   LOOP
      -- display substring
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (TRIM (la_Tab_Str (i)));
   END LOOP;

   OPEN v_cur FOR
      SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT REPLACE (TRIM (la_Tab_Str (2)), '"', '') AS Firstname,
                     REPLACE (TRIM (la_Tab_Str (4)), '"', '') AS Surname,
                     REPLACE (TRIM (la_Tab_Str (6)), '"', '') AS Address,
                     REPLACE (TRIM (la_Tab_Str (8)), '"', '') AS City,
                     REPLACE (TRIM (la_Tab_Str (10)), '"', '') AS Country
                FROM DUAL) t;
END;
```

I hard coded in the string but it could come in as a variable then replace your semicolons with commas.

when I ran the following in toad to test it.

```
DECLARE 
  V_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN 
  V_CUR := NULL;

  MYPROC ( V_CUR );
  :to_grid := V_CUR;
  COMMIT; 
END;
```

I got

```
FIRSTNAME SURNAME  ADDRESS           CITY     COUNTRY
Bob       Smith    101 High Street   London   UK
```